# Azure is not using bowerrc to change install directory for components

Tags: azure, deployment, bower, bower-install

I am deploying a .NET application to Azure via bitbucket. 
The project contains some **bower** dependencies and so I am using a **custom** deploy script to manage this.

This works fine using the code below.

```
echo Install bower packages

IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\bower.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"

  ::remove existing components
  call rm -rf bower_components      
  call bower install

  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)
)
```

However, I want the components installed in a different folder.
Therefore I added a **.bowerrc** file and specified the new location there:

```
{
  "directory": "Client/bower_components/"
}
```

But Azure continues to install the dependencies into the default **bower_components** folder.

Both **bower.json** and **.bowerrc** are in the root of the project. I want the bower dependencies installed one level down, in the Client folder.

How can I achieve this?
Why is Azure not using the .bowerrc file?

> Note: this works as expected locally. I.e. running bower install,
>   installs the components in the directory specified in .bowerrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a shout out for help on this on Twitter and Azure Support responded within minutes. One week later and the issue has been resolved.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I had to move my bower.json inside wwwroot folder